# Windows Deployment Services: Can I rerun first boot steps?

Tags: windows, wds

I'm experimenting with WDS. So far I've got the first half going well. I can boot and install the OS. However the customization steps aren't going so well. However, every time I make a change I have to totally reinstall. Is there a way to start at part 4?

Comment: Where are you getting your information on how to WDS?
All I did was install DHCP, WDS and made it a standalone server. I then added a Boot image and one install image that corresponds to the same version of boot image. I made sure that the server was enabled and running and then booted a device via PXE.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question. There is a tool that works with WDS called MDT, Microsoft Deployment Toolkit. You can set up the MDT to only run the 4th step. If you want to test just that step. I think that would help you tremendously.